# How to add role member for existing database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlroleprovider

I want to add role member to my databases dynamically with the help of below query:

```
use MyExistingDatabase
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_owner', @membername = 'A38'
GO 
execute as user='A38'
GO
CREATE TABLE [A38].[ABC] ( 
[Id]             int              IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
[Name]  nvarchar(100)                             NULL,
```

Here `A38` is my username in `MyExistingDatabase` and wants to execute the further script with default schema `A38`. The above script is working fine in case if I create a new database but if I used my any existing database, it throws the following error:

> User does not have permission to perform this action
>
> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyExistingDatabase'

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the table with a schema called A38, so you need to make sure that the schema exists, like this:

```
use MyExistingDatabase
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'A38'
GO 
CREATE SCHEMA A38 AUTHORIZATION A38
GO 
CREATE TABLE [A38].[ABC] ( 
[Id]             int              IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
[Name]  nvarchar(100)                             NULL)
```

Otherwise see this [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1227/granting-permission-with-the-execute-as-command-in-sql-server/) for an alternate method.